# Really Big Sky Spaceship Upgrades explained

Tags: really-big-sky

Can someone explain me what each upgrade does, because some of them don't even make sense.

Here's an in-game screenshot of the available upgrades.
[image: WIDEBAND, POLARSHOT, CONTRA, COHERENCE, FREQUENCY, MAGNETCOIL, ELECTROMAGNET, ORBITAL, CLAYMORE, BASE ENGINE, RADIOSHIELD, WINGCANNON]

I want to know what Wideband, Polarshot and Contra do, to begin with. It says "Fires 2 shots at 45 degrees", but what exactly does it mean? When the cross is 45 degrees nothing changes, same with 90 and 180 which is about the other two upgrades.

Comment: Edits automatically put the question into a queue for users who have the Reopen privilege to look at. If it's gonna get re-opened, it should happen in the next day or so.

Comment: It hasn't been deleted, so anyone can see it, but On Hold means it's not answerable. Take a look at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Those refers to the peripheral lasers you get coming out at various angles to your main laser. Here's an image to illustrate

[image]

- Wideband - lasers come out 45 degrees on either side relative to the main laser
- Polarshot - lasers coming out 90 degrees on either side
- Contra - lasers coming out 180 degrees at the back
- Wingcannon - fast yellow/orange colored lasers accompanying your main laser